# Taxonomy Drop Down with hierarchical view using $terms

Tags: terms

I asked this on the Wordpress forum but dint get any replies now I hope I can ask it here.

I found the code [here](http://frankiejarrett.com/2011/09/create-a-dropdown%20of-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-the-easy-way/) My Code is:

```
function exc_custom_taxonomy_dropdown( $taxonomy, $orderby, $order, $hierarchical, $show_count,  $name) {
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_count' => true,
    );
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
    $name = ( $name ) ? $name : $taxonomy;
    if ( $terms ) {
        printf( '<select name="%s" class="postform">', $name );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            printf( '<option value="%s">%s (%s)</option>', $term->slug, $term->name, $term->count );
        }
        print( '</select>' );
    }
}
?>
<form role="search" method="get" id="equipfilter" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
        <fieldset>
           <?php exc_custom_taxonomy_dropdown( 'exc_equipment_cat', 'name', 'ASC', true, true, 'exc_equipment_cat'); ?>
-       </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Kw Range:</legend>
            <input type="text" name="kw_min" placeholder="from" value><br />
            <input type="text" name="kw_max" placeholder="to" value>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Price Range:</legend>
            <input type="text" name="pr_min" placeholder="from" value><br />
            <input type="text" name="pr_max" placeholder="to" value>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" id="filtersubmit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

It creates a drop down for my custom taxonomy. It works 100% I just cant get it to show my categories with hierarchy like it would with wp_dropdown_categories.

I have tried to use wp_dropdown_categories with a walker but it outputs a slug website.com?equipment_cat instead of website.com/equipment_cat.

Here is my code for the wp_dropdown_categories with walker.

```
<?php
// Equipment Category Dropdown, thanks https://gist.github.com/2902509
class Walker_SlugValueCategoryDropdown extends Walker_CategoryDropdown {

        function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) {
        $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);

        $cat_name = apply_filters('list_cats', $category->name, $category);
        $output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"".$category->slug."\"";
        if ( $category->term_id == $args['selected'] )
            $output .= ' selected="selected"';
        $output .= '>';
        $output .= $pad.$cat_name;
        if ( $args['show_count'] )
            $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;('. $category->count .')';
        if (isset ( $args['show_last_update'] ) ) {
            $format = 'Y-m-d';
            $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . gmdate($format, $category->last_update_timestamp);
        }
        $output .= "</option>\n";
    }
}
?>
<form role="search" method="get" id="equipfilter" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
        <fieldset>
            <?php
            $dropdown_args = array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'exc_equipment_cat',
                'name'          => 'equipment_cat',
                'show_option_none'  => 'Select category',
                'show_count'        => 1,
                'orderby'       => 'name',
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'echo'          => 1,
                'walker'            => new Walker_SlugValueCategoryDropdown);

            wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown_args );
            ?>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Kw Range:</legend>
            <input type="text" name="kw_min" placeholder="from" value><br />
            <input type="text" name="kw_max" placeholder="to" value>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Price Range:</legend>
            <input type="text" name="pr_min" placeholder="from" value><br />
            <input type="text" name="pr_max" placeholder="to" value>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" id="filtersubmit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

Help would really be appreciated.

Comment: When using the wp_dropdown_categories code my url is /?equipment_cat=ripper&kw_min=&kw_max=&pr_min=&pr_max= (doens't work) but when I use the terms code the url is /equipment-cat/implemente/ripper/?kw_min&kw_max&pr_min&pr_max (works) how can I get the url to work with wp_dropdown_categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can kick myself, been struggling for 2 days and all that I had to do to make the  wp_dropdown_categories option work is change the name to the same value as the taxonomy.

My complete working code is:

```
<?php
// Equipment Category Dropdown, thanks https://gist.github.com/2902509
class Walker_SlugValueCategoryDropdown extends Walker_CategoryDropdown {

        function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) {
        $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);

        $cat_name = apply_filters('list_cats', $category->name, $category);
        $output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"".$category->slug."\"";
        if ( $category->term_id == $args['selected'] )
            $output .= ' selected="selected"';
        $output .= '>';
        $output .= $pad.$cat_name;
        if ( $args['show_count'] )
            $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;('. $category->count .')';
        if (isset ( $args['show_last_update'] ) ) {
            $format = 'Y-m-d';
            $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . gmdate($format, $category->last_update_timestamp);
        }
        $output .= "</option>\n";
    }
}
?>
<form role="search" method="get" id="equipfilter" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
        <fieldset>
            <?php
            $dropdown_args = array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'exc_equipment_cat',
                'name'          => 'exc_equipment_cat',
                'show_option_none'  => 'Select category',
                'show_count'        => 1,
                'orderby'       => 'name',
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'echo'          => 1,
                'walker'            => new Walker_SlugValueCategoryDropdown);

            wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown_args );
            ?>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Kw Range:</legend>
            <input type="text" name="kw_min" placeholder="from" value><br />
            <input type="text" name="kw_max" placeholder="to" value>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Price Range:</legend>
            <input type="text" name="pr_min" placeholder="from" value><br />
            <input type="text" name="pr_max" placeholder="to" value>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" id="filtersubmit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```